# How to display a parsed integer string in a textview

Tags: android, textview

I'm having difficulties getting a string containing the user's input and displaying it in a textview when the button is clicked. For example, if the user types *10* and click the button, I want the textview to display *10*. I get a warning saying that *answerINT* is never used.

**The code I'm having difficulties with**

```
                //Fetches user answer and converts it into an integer
                EditText answer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editanswer); {
                if (answer.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                    int answerInt = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString());

                    //Display answer in textview on click
                    TextView displayanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplayanswer);
                    displayanswer.setText(answer);

                }
```

**The coode in it's context**

```
            findViewById(R.id.btnok).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("onClick", "OK button was clicked");

                //Fetches user answer and converts it into an integer
                EditText answer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editanswer); {
                if (answer.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                    int answerInt = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString());

                    //Display answer in textview on click
                    TextView displayanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplayanswer);
                    displayanswer.setText(answer);

                }
            //Displaying a toast if no answer is provided
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No answer provided!",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 displayanswer.setText(" "+answerInt);
```

OR

```
displayanswer.setText(String.valueOf(answerInt));
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer allows me to do so! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
displayanswer.setText(""+answerInt);
```

Comment: Please add some commentary. Code only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String.valueOf(yourint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it this way:

```
if (answer.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                //Display answer in textview on click
                TextView displayanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplayanswer);
                displayanswer.setText(answer.getText().toString());

            }
```